# Missing posts at user's feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For our Facebook application we query users' public feed/posts/statuses using Graph API
(to be clear: the application queries not the data of the user that uses our application, but other users' public data).

We use:

```
graph.facebook.com/#facebook_userId#/feed?access_token=#access_token#

graph.facebook.com/#facebook_userId#/posts?access_token=#access_token#

graph.facebook.com/#facebook_userId#/statuses?access_token=#access_token#
```

We use our application user's valid access token to make the query.

The problem:

For some of the users we query, we get no results on feed or posts, and get partial and outdated data when querying statuses

For other users we get data when using feed, but it's not all the posts on the wall (we have noticed the missing posts are ones with photos).

Can someone explain this behavior? Is there a way to get the full public data from a user's wall?

We opened a bug on http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20339 but will be grateful if someone helps us here.

Comment: We have posted the question on this forum after a comprehensive research, in which we found more developers that were asking a similar question, but were never given an answer. Do we have a way of getting all the posts from a user's wall using the Graph API ? What could be the reason of getting only part of the posts or none of them, even if posts are public? It's a lasting, non-localized problem. We encounter it while trying to retrieve the full data of many users' walls.

Comment: @BrianRoach I have the same problem and the questions is not localized at all.

Comment: I cannot help you but link u've used are great!